# How to handle errors returned by Process class?

Tags: c#, error-handling, process, runtime-error

I use a proxy class in which I wrap a Process instance, I've implemented the ErrorDataReceived event that forwards to the real Process event. But either way - even without the proxy class - I just don't understand how to use this event.

The Problem is that the static Process.Start() returns a Process instance to which I can hook up my event handlers. So basically I cannot subscribe to the event before the process has been started, but then I don't have anything to subscribe to and in my case that gives me a NullReferenceException because my wrapped Process instance is null at that point.

But can I be sure that the error hasn't already occurred between invoking and subscribing? Does anybody know a better solution to catch errors? This process class is bugging me quite a bit, there are multiple ways of doing things, som are not entirely clear to me. Also reading the ErrorOutputStream blocks the application if there are no errors...

A bit of context:

```
public class ProcessProxy : IProcessProxy
{
    private object lockObject = new object();

    public Process Process { get; private set; }

    public void Start(ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo)
    {
        Process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }

    public bool WaitForExit(int milliseconds)
    {
        return Process.WaitForExit(milliseconds);
    }

    public event DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorDataReceived
    {
        add
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Process.ErrorDataReceived += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Process.ErrorDataReceived -= value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I do s.th. like this, then this obviously is a NullReferenceException because the internal Process object is null:

```
AprocessProxy.ErrorDataReceived += OnError;
processProxy.Start(ProcessStartInfo);
```

Comment: there are other methods to start a Process other than the static method `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`. You can construct a `Process` instance using `Process process = new Process(ProcessStartInfo)`, then wire up the events, and then call `process.Start();` on that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new` to construct a `Process` instance, wire up the event handler, and then start the process by calling `Start` method on that instance.